# Karaf container not able to use proxy

Tags: java, talend, apache-karaf

I have `talend` job and below java code works well while running on `talend` studio it returns object for `proxySelector`

```
java.net.ProxySelector proxySelector =proxySearch.getProxySelector();
```

but same job when I deploy to karaf container proxySelector is coming as null.

My `karaf` and studio are on same machine.

Comment: How is the proxy configured for Karaf?

Comment: Thanks for reply .I have not configured anything for karaf .Any configuration need to be done ?

Comment: Yes. Adding `http.proxyHost=your.proxy.ip` and `http.proxyPort=your.proxy.port` to `${karaf_home}/etc/system.properties` should do it.